# Everything except mouse pointer freezes when holding backspace at end of line and with workspace switcher

Tags: graphics, mouse, gnome-terminal, freeze, workspaces

Inside of the Gnome Terminal that comes prepackaged with Ubuntu, I get a problem where if I'm deleting a line and holding backspace and I reach the beginning of the line, everything except the mouse pointer freezes for anywhere in between 5 and 10 seconds. Similar problem happens whenever I'm switching workspaces. In those cases, it only happens for around 3 seconds.

This is only weird to me because everything else is buttery smooth and never freezes up. I've been having this problem for months on Ubuntu 18.04. Is anyone else having this problem? Does anyone have any solutions?

Comment: I guess it's related to some beeping sound the terminal plays (or at least tries to play). Try disabling "Terminal bell" in the preferences, does that help?

Comment: @egmont That helps with the Terminal problem, but what about the workspace switcher?